How do I check if my android device is in silent mode(DND mode) on a button's press unity?
I have a Project, where i check sound and music's volume by Audio source. when my Volume is High and I press Device's Mute Button than Project's Sound Doesn't Mute.

So for it's solution i need to know that how to check that when android device's DND mode is on/off?
Can Anyone Help me without any Criticizing❔

You can check it like this:
 public boolean isMuted()
    {
        AudioManager audio = context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if (audio.getRingerMode() == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL) return false;
        else return true;
    }

and call isMuted() where you need it

It doesn't work
